# Why can't I get XML autofac configuration to work

Tags: xml, configuration, autofac

I followed the example here http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html, substituting XML for json, but can't get anything to compile.  I referenced the package Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Xml (version 1.0.0-beta4), and added the code:

```
// Add the configuration to the ConfigurationBuilder.
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
config.AddXmlFile("something.xml");

// Register the ConfigurationModule with Autofac.
var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(module);
```

The trouble is, the extension method AddXmlFile() takes an IConfigurationSourceRoot parameter, which the ConfigurationBuilder is not a type of.  Tinkering around I found that the AddXmlFile() method only seems to like a Configuration object:

```
var config = new Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Configuration();
config.AddXmlFile(filename);
```

But there is no Build() method on a Configuration class, member or extension.  What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc shows `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` not `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration`. Microsoft renamed a lot of stuff before releasing .NET Core so it appears you're referencing the wrong thing. Try using the full release versions of everything and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Good catch.  It wasn't that long ago that all you needed was Autofac.Configuration.  Now you need that plus 8 other packages.  Also, json configs work, but not xml ones.  This produces a duplicate key error:

<autofac defaultAssembly="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
  <modules>
    <module type="SomeModule"/>
    <module type="AnotherModule"/>
  </modules>

Comment: Read the docs. You're missing the ordinal naming of XML items. http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html

Comment: Actually, the docs only talk about using ordinals for <component>, not  <module>.  From their doc:

<modules>
    <module type="MyModule" />

In any case, I tried adding the "name" attribute previously and it still doesn't work.  It gets me past the duplicate key error right into an ArgumentNullException.  The exact same config works in json.  What you see is literally all I'm doing - including two modules.  Json it is.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wrote the docs. I know what they say. The problem is, the "how to express ordinal config" is a question of how to use the Microsoft configuration. The docs try to give as much info as possible, but just like with web.config, if you're not familiar with the system, it's going to be harder and it's impossible for us to reproduce every possible permutation of their docs as applied to our schema. However, seriously, JSON will be far easier to work with and is the standard they use to express configuration, too. Best to stick with that.